# How to set default folder when open Dialog Form Upload

Tags: javascript, html

How to set default folder when open dialog Form Upload

Ex:

I want to set defualt \192.168.1.100

[image]

On html , I set

> `<input type="file" class=" form-control text-right  " value="\\192.168.1.100\Sharing"   accept=".csv"  directory="\\192.168.1.100\Sharing" id="upload_file">`

But it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it, it is a security risk.

Also, you can never be sure that directory exists.

If you try to show path, it will be `C:\\fakepath\\`

Comment: I set 
<input type="file" class=" form-control text-right  " value="\\192.168.1.100\Sharing"   accept=".csv"  directory="\\192.168.1.100\Sharing" id="upload_file">

But it is not working

Comment: You don’t need try it because it is impossible, I tried it before